# how to remove scrollbar from home page and show in other pages?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i would like to know how to hide the scrollbar in homepage and show in other pages.

i have  used the following code

> html { overflow-y: hidden; }

What should i add to make this code just work for the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Add this html `{ overflow-y: hidden; }` just to your home page like this example

> home page

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html { 
        overflow-y: hidden; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

> other pages

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

> [Here](https://amethystwebsitedesign.com/add-unique-custom-styles-to-one-wordpress-page-or-post/) is how to do it to your wordpress

Comment: Im working in wordpress . i have a section called CSS where i can add the code. how do i specify the code is just meant to work for the homepage

Comment: @EhtizadZashkiyor Then add wordpress tag to your question

Comment: I have updated the answer the link is in the bottom @EhtizadZashkiyor

Answer (score 0):

If you only want this behaviour on homepage, add this to `style.css`

```
body.home {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Press Ctrl Shift R in Windows or Cmd Shift R in Mac to hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the unique id or class for the homepage to apply this CSS property. If there is none, you can add it on runtime in your home page template using script:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').addClass('home');
});
```

and then add CSS:

```
body.home{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```